# Show that $2^\mathbb{N} $ is equinumerous with $2^\mathbb{N\times N} $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to show that $2^\mathbb{N} $ is equinumerous with  $2^\mathbb{N\times N} $.

I already found a function from $2^\mathbb{N} $ to  $2^\mathbb{N \times N} $, wich just returns a pair containing the same element repeated, but I can't find a function wich goes from  $2^\mathbb{N\times N} $ to $2^\mathbb{N} $, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a [one-to-one correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between $2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$ and $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee you just need two injections, then for Cantor-Bernstein theorem, the two sets are equipollent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Start with a bijection $p:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$; if you want a specific one, the [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) works fine. Use $p$ to construct a map $A\mapsto p[A]$ from $2^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}$ to $2^{\Bbb N}$, and show that this map is a bijection.

Comment: Or, much more easily, with an injection $p : \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $p(i, j) = 2^i3^j$, which extends naturally to an injection between the power sets.

Comment: @rewritten: That is not a bijection. Had I wanted to use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem, I’d have done so.

Comment: I won't object to that. But te OP already used an injection on one side, so why not using an injection on the other side too?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is equinumerous with $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ -- to get the bijection, think of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ as the upper quadrant of the integer lattice in the plane. Then start at the origin, go up one, right one, down one, right one, up two, left two, up one, right three, etc.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about that, could you please be more specific? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know that $\mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z$, and $\mathbb Q$ are all equinumerous, then all you need is an injection $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$.